# How to evaluate two enum members with same value as not equal in C#?

Tags: c#, enums

I have this enum instance

```
public enum MyEnum {A1 = 0, A2 = 0}
```

where I want the members `A1` `A2` to yield the same value when evaluated but should not be considered equal when compared.

Hence in the following function

```
private int evalEnum(MyEnum enumInstance) {
    if(enumInstance == MyEnum.A1) 
        //some logic
    else if(enumInstance == MyEnum.A2)
        //some logic

    return (int) enumInstance;
}
```

I don't want the function to enter the first `if` statement if `enumInstance` is of type `A2`. I have tried to use `Equals` and `CompareTo` as well but as to my understanding they also evaluates to `true` (`0`) in the first if statement as long as `A1` and `A2` are assigned to the same value.

So in conclusion; it possible to evaluate `A1` and `A2` as not equal even if they are assigned the same value? If so, what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You can't - the underlying value is stored as an `int` so it's not possible to distinguish between them.

Comment: Willy-nilly you have to assign different values to `A1` and `A2`; but may be you could use flags? `[Flags] public enum MyEnum {AnyA = 1, A1 = 2, A2 = 3}` so you have `AnyA` for either `A1` or `A2` and exact `A2` and `A3` values

Comment: @MatthewWatson I see, it does make complete sense but I was hoping there was a clever work around. Thanks!

Comment: The whole *point* of assigning the same values is to create an alias, so they *are* the same thing. *"the same value when evaluated but should not be considered equal when compared"* makes no sense as a sentence: if they compare the same they are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy work around that is most suffiecient for my problem.

That is to simply use modulo to allow all members in `MyEnum` to have different values while still evaluate to the same value.

This method also made it very easy to add enum members to `MyEnum` and without taking up any extra memory space.

```
public enum MyEnum {A1 = 0, A2 = 10, A3 = 20, B1 = 1, B2 = 11, B3 = 21,...}
```

```
private int evalEnum(MyEnum enumInstance) {
    if(enumInstance == MyEnum.A1) 
        //some logic
    else if(enumInstance == MyEnum.A2)
        //some logic
    else if(enumInstance == MyEnum.B1)
    .
    .
    .
    return ((int) enumInstance) % 10;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this with just an enum. Enums are simply int values with assigned names, there is no way to distinguish A1 from A2 since they have the same actual value.

You need some intermediate mapping, for example:

```
public enum MyEnum {A1 , A2 }
public Dictionary<MyEnum, int> MyEnumToValue = new (){{MyEnum.A1, 0},{MyEnum.A2, 0}};
```

That gives you an easy way to get the same value from A1/A2, while still allowing them to compare as not equal.

Answer (score 1):

Since `enum` is in fact an integer type (`byte`, `int`, `long` etc.) you will-nilly have to assign *different* values
to `A1` and `A2`: having

```
public enum MyEnum {
  A1 = 0, 
  A2 = 0
};
```

and there's no way to distinguish `A1` and `A2` to compiler

```
// if (enumInstance == 0) 
if (enumInstance == MyEnum.A1) 
  ...
// else if (enumInstance == 0) 
else if(enumInstance == MyEnum.A2)
  ... // <- unreachable code
```

If you have situations like "either `A1` or `A2`" - the reason why you are trying to assign the *same* value to both `A1` and `A2` and you insist on `enum`, you can try marking the `enum` with `[Flags]` attribute

```
[Flags]
public enum MyEnum {
  None = 0b000, // Neither A1 or A2
  A    = 0b001, // Either A1 or A2
  A1   = 0b011, // Exactly A1  
  A2   = 0b111, // Exactly A2
};
```

then

```
if (enumInstance.HasFlag(MyEnum.A)) {
  // Either A1 or A2
}

if (enumInstance == MyEnum.A2) {
  // Exactly A2
}
```